# How to send and receive USSD by using kannel

Tags: sms-gateway, smpp, kannel, ussd

I am new in USSD but i am already sending message using Kannel 1.5.4 since long. 
I want send/receive USSD request by using kannel. I have smpp v5 account for the same. 
It's better if anyone help me by configuration file. 
my configuration file is:

```
#SMSC CONNECTIONS
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = USSD-ACC
host= 10.*.*.*
port= 1234
transceiver-mode=true
smsc-username = "USER"
smsc-password = "PWD"
system-type = ""
interface-version=34
source-addr-ton=5
source-addr-npi=0
dest-addr-ton=0
dest-addr-npi=1
max-pending-submits=10
wait-ack=600
wait-ack-expire=0x01

# SMSBOX SETUP
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 12345
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
log-file = "/tmp/kannel_smsbox.log"
log-level = 3
# SERVICES
group = sms-service
keyword = default
get-url = "http://localhost/request.php?MNO=%p&SHORTCODE=%P&CONTENT=%a"
name="*123#"
max-messages=0

group = sendsms-user
username = ussd
password = ussd
user-deny-ip  = *.*.*.*"
user-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
max-messages = 5
concatenation = true
default-sender = "123"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you need to use **smpp-tlv** section to pass **ussd_service_op** TLV to/from USSDC.

See [this link](http://mehulbhatt.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/connect-kannel-to-a-ussd-centered/) for configuration examples: